# 2 weeks until marathon, missed the past month of training, what should I focus on?

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running, running-training-plan, marathon

I've spent the past 4 months training for my first marathon. Last month I came down with the gnarliest of sinus infections and missed a full 4 weeks of training.

Now I have 2 weeks until my marathon. What should I focus on doing as far as training goes?

Farthest I've run is 16 miles, and that was 4 weeks ago, right before I got sick. I don't have a time goal, other than to finish under the 6 hours time limit.

Comment: How'd it go? It'd be great to hear, especially if you took the advice below, how it worked out.

Comment: The race ended up getting rescheduled for two weeks later (due to weather). So I got an additional couple of weeks of training! I finished the race, however I ended up with a pretty minor stress fracture. Who knows if it was due to the reduction in training or something else. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two weeks to go, aim for a long run, 20 miles or so. See how it feels, and be prepared to cut it short. Run slow, but try to keep good running form, high cadence etc.    In the last two weeks adapt your normal training pattern 60% distance this week. 40% of normal next week. I wouldn't do any single run in excess of 7 miles. Have the day before the race off. Day before that do 3 miles of intervals or repeats. Good luck.